# Custom NTP client getting wrong timestamps

Tags: c++, timestamp, client, ntp

I'm trying to implement my own NTP client. I can send a request to a NTP server and I get a response. Everything in the response looks correct, except for the four timestamps that are wrong. I've looked up the message sent from the NTP server in wireshark and there everything is correct. For example, this is the data wireshark is displaying from the Reference TimeStamp

d8 c6 36 c3 ae 40 00 00

And this is what my program gets as the Refernece Timestamp

d8 c6 3f 1d b0 00 00 00

My code for receiving data from the NTP server looks like this:

```
addr_len = sizeof(their_addr);
uint8_t buffer[64];
memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
recvfrom(sockfd, (char*)buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&their_addr, &addr_len);
```

Can someone help me figure out where things are going wrong?

Comment: Did you verify that you have received the entire timestamp? Initialising `buffer` to `{0}` makes uninitialised elements clearer.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm pretty sure, becase I get the correct beginning of all the four timestamps. Or maybe im just getting 90 % of every timestamp but that seems unlikely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I forgot to convert the timestamps I recieved from Network byte order to Host byte order.